# Linq To Twitter clearing IOAuthCredentials credentials

Tags: c#, linq-to-twitter

I have a piece of functionality that creates a voice message and if authenticated through Twitter, will post a message to their Twitter account. I want the ability for the user to turn off the message posting to Twitter if they desire, so I was curious if there was a way to clear the credentials. I followed an example from the LinqToTwitter documentation:

```
IOAuthCredentials credentials = new SessionStateCredentials();

        if (credentials.ConsumerKey == null || credentials.ConsumerSecret == null)
        {
            credentials.ConsumerKey = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["twitterConsumerKey"];
            credentials.ConsumerSecret = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["twitterConsumerSecret"];
        }

        auth = new WebAuthorizer
        {
            Credentials = credentials,
            PerformRedirect = authUrl => Response.Redirect(authUrl)
        };

        if (!Page.IsPostBack && Request.QueryString["oauth_token"] != null)
        {
            auth.CompleteAuthorization(Request.Url);
        }

        if (auth.IsAuthorized)
        {
            twitterCtx = new TwitterContext(auth);
            Session["TwitterContext"] = twitterCtx;
            twLoginButton.Text = "Logout of Twitter";
        }
```

I've tried the following code and variations:

```
credentials = null;
```

or

```
SessionStateCredentials credentials = Dispose();
```

But it shows errors for each of these. I was hoping someone could guide me in clearing out

```
IOAuthCredentials credentials = new SessionStateCredentials();
```

which is what I think needs to happen. Any advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The SessionStateCredentials type has properties that use Session state as their backing store. Here are a few options, with pros and cons of each:

1. Set the properties to null. e.g.

   credentials.ConsumerKey = null;
   credentials.ConsumerSecret = null;
   // etc ...

This is a little ugly, though you could write a method to encapsulate the statements.

1. Clear out the individual Session state items. e.g.

   Session.Remove("ConsumerKey");
   Session.Remove("ConsumerSecret");
   // etc ...

This is more explicit. However, it breaks the existing encapsulation and forces you to obtain a reference to the current session.

1. Derive a new class from SessionStateCredentials with a Clear method that performs the steps from one of the previous methods. This might be the cleanest option.

Here's a link to the SessionStateCredentials class so you can see the internal implementation:

http://linqtotwitter.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#LinqToTwitter/OAuth/SessionStateCredentials.cs

Comment: I'm trying to clear the credentials in code behind on a button click and used the Session.Remove idea. When I would try to re-authenticate, I'd get a 401 error. Can you explain what you meant by obtaining a reference to the current session? I appreciate it.

Comment: If you're logic is in a library, you would need to add a project reference the System.Web.dll, add a using statement for System.Web, and reference the HttpContext.Current.Session property (like I do in the answer link). Since you're in code-behind, as you know, you can just say Session. The reason for the 401 is because you probably cleared out ConsumerKey and ConsumerSecret. I didn't know what you were trying to do, so I mentioned those in my answer. If you want to re-authenticate with the same authorizer, leave ConsumerKey and ConsumerSecret alone and only clear OAuthToken and AccessToken.